# How do I install the Discord certificate without Internet Explorer?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been having some trouble developing a bot with Discord.py on my Macbook. I've already installed the latest version of Discord.py (1.15.0) and have Python 3.8.5. Whenever I try to run simple code like:

```
import discord 


client = discord.Client()




client.run('NzU1NDAxMTE0NTU5NDQ3MDYx.X2CwHA.krJ3LTq2W6fuss6HpSbQ6cOd6i4')
```

I receive errors like:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1050, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1080, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 529, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mika/Desktop/python-test/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    client.run('NzU1NDAxMTE0NTU5NDQ3MDYx.X2CwHA.krJ3LTq2W6fuss6HpSbQ6cOd6i4')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 708, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 687, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 650, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 499, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 291, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 480, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 938, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')]
```

After searching up for solutions, I've gathered that I need Internet Explorer and run it as an Administrator, then go to discord.com and go to the top left and click on the security lock. Then download certificates. I don't have Internet Explorer, I use Brave Browser. When I go onto the discord website and click the top left icon, I don't see any way to install a certificate.

Does anyone know what to do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You must change your token NOW, it has been exposed.

Comment: @Abdulaziz yeah that's my old cert. But do you have an answer to my question?

Comment: use microsoft edge

Comment: @Poojan I've downloaded Microsoft Edge, but it still does not give me an option to download any certificate. It just says "Certificate Valid"

Comment: make sure to open edge as admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started writing my own discord bot on my MacBook.

Go to your Applications folder.
Open your python3.x folder and run the "Install Certificates.comman" shellscript.

or:

Open your terminal and enter "./../../../Applications/Python\ 3.8/Install\ Certificates.command"

It solved the problem for me. Also, I recommend using environment variables for storing your token, then you can show your code to anyone.